# Excel problem with sum if formula and its range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this setup in my worksheet:

```
  A        B     C           D          E        F
1 11-apr   1pm   2pm         START      END      TOTAL
2          2pm   3pm         11-apr     14-apr   8,50 h
3          6pm   7pm         15-apr     25-apr   ....
4          7pm   8pm
5 14-apr   10am  11am
6          12am  12:30am
7          2pm   3pm
8          3pm   5pm
9 15-apr   1pm   3pm
10         6pm   7pm
...
```

and I need to do the following:

sum how many hours are spent per day between 11-apr and 14-apr taking D2 and E2 as start-end point and write the total in F2.
I cannot modify my worksheet and I prefer to not create hidden cell for referring value as I don't want to mess with my excel sheets.

What I'm looking for is, as I have some few programming skills, do a for-loop between A:A cells and start at row where is "11-apr" (in this case A1) and going down till I found "14-apr" and stop just before the next day cell ( so at A8 ). I prefer also to not make a macro because it needs to be dynamic in respect of columns D and E.
Dates in A are random, so no method to provide the next day coming.

I ask you if this is possible in one single formula in cell F2.

What I have done is to look for ref. rows of "11-apr" and "14-apr", then in an array formula find what cells are not empty ( like `INT(A:A<>"")` ) and with that returned array I want to do a sum from "11-apr" row till the next-non-empty-cell-after-"14-apr"-row minus 1 ( until `"15-apr" row` - 1 ), that is the next non 0 (non FALSE) value in the array AFTER row of "14-apr" minus 1. I combined a lot of formulas with MATCH, INDEX, LARGE for getting the nth-element but uselessly.

Hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm on Excel for Mac, in case it's usefull to know!

Comment: Instead of telling us what you have tried, forcing us to try and reconstruct your formula, *show* us what you have tried. In other words, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55800756/edit) to give us the formula you used

Comment: Are you willing to use a custom vba function?

Comment: are the times `1pm` a string or a time that is formatted that way?

Comment: no worry about formatting, I'm ok with the dates columns. I made a description of what I tried, no working solutions nor working try, I cannot do this that's why I'm asking here.
I'm on Excel for Mac, I don't know it very well so I don't know if vba functions are the right solutions for me... I prefer a formula if possible

Comment: you could do this in a single formula, but it would be quite complex. I would write vba

Comment: Is it possible in Excel 2011 on mac? If so, how could I write vba function? Just to know, but I prefer in one single formula, at last if it's possible

Comment: It would be much easier, if the all the dates were filled in without empty cells, then a `sumproduct`would be sufficient. Would it be a problem to do this?

Comment: Yes I know, infact for another sheet I don't have any empty cells between dates and it's as easy as you say for the sum if in range. For this sheet alas I can't fill empty spaces in there between dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These non-volatile Formulas Array are based on @OverflowStacker approach to identifying the `Target Range`, they use `INDEX` instead of `INDIRECT`:

*FormulaArrays are entered pressing* <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> *simultaneously, you shall see the formula wrapped between `{` and `}` if entered correctly.*

This piece validates the dates provided:

```
=IF( Start > End, "!Err",
```

This is the `FormulaArray` used to obtain the addition of the hours as per the `Start` and `End` times provided:

```
= SUM(
INDEX( Column.End , MATCH( MIN( IF( Range.Dates >= Start, Range.Dates ) ), Column.Dates , 0 ) ) :
INDEX( Column.End , MATCH( MIN( IF( Range.Dates > End, Range.Dates ) ), Column.Dates , 0 ) - 1 ),
-INDEX( Column.Start , MATCH( MIN( IF( Range.Dates >= Start, Range.Dates ) ), Column.Dates , 0 ) ) :
INDEX( Column.Start , MATCH( MIN( IF( Range.Dates > End, Range.Dates ) ), Column.Dates , 0 ) - 1 ) ) )
```

The `Start`, `End` and `Total` times could be represented as a `TimeSerial` or as a `Double` (e.g. `12:30 AM` or `0.5` respectively)

This table shows the formula to be used depending on the time format required:

[image]

*Applying the formulas:*

1. Table 1 shows the times as `TimeSerial`

a.  Total as `TimeSerial`: Enter this `ArrayFormula` in `I7` then copy downwards *(cells number format is `[hh]:mm`)*

```
= IF( $G7 > $H7, "!Err", SUM(
  INDEX($E:$E, MATCH( MIN( IF( $C$7:$C$27 >= $G7, $C$7:$C$27 ) ),$C:$C, 0 ) ) :
  INDEX($E:$E, MATCH( MIN( IF( $C$7:$C$27 > $H7, $C$7:$C$27 ) ),$C:$C, 0 ) - 1 ),
- INDEX($D:$D, MATCH( MIN( IF( $C$7:$C$27 >= $G7, $C$7:$C$27 ) ),$C:$C, 0 ) ) :
  INDEX($D:$D, MATCH( MIN( IF( $C$7:$C$27 > $H7, $C$7:$C$27 ) ),$C:$C, 0 ) - 1 ) ) )
```

b. Total as `Double`: Enter this `ArrayFormula` in `J7` then copy downwards *(cells number format is `0.?? "Hrs."`)*

```
= IF( $G7 > $H7, "!Err", 24 * SUM(
  INDEX($E:$E, MATCH( MIN( IF( $C$7:$C$27 >= $G7, $C$7:$C$27 ) ),$C:$C, 0 ) ) :
  INDEX($E:$E, MATCH( MIN( IF( $C$7:$C$27 > $H7, $C$7:$C$27 ) ),$C:$C, 0 ) - 1 ),
- INDEX($D:$D, MATCH( MIN( IF( $C$7:$C$27 >= $G7, $C$7:$C$27 ) ),$C:$C, 0 ) ) :
  INDEX($D:$D, MATCH( MIN( IF( $C$7:$C$27 > $H7, $C$7:$C$27 ) ),$C:$C, 0 ) - 1 ) ) )
```

2. Table 1 shows the times as `Double`

a.  Total as `Double`: Enter this `ArrayFormula` in `S7` then copy downwards *(cells number format is `0.?? "Hrs."`)*

```
= IF( $Q7 > $R7, "!Err", SUM(
  INDEX($O:$O, MATCH( MIN( IF( $M$7:$M$27 >= $Q7, $M$7:$M$27 ) ),$M:$M, 0 ) ) :
  INDEX($O:$O, MATCH( MIN( IF( $M$7:$M$27 > $R7, $M$7:$M$27 ) ),$M:$M, 0 ) - 1 ),
- INDEX($N:$N, MATCH( MIN( IF( $M$7:$M$27 >= $Q7, $M$7:$M$27 ) ),$M:$M, 0 ) ) :
  INDEX($N:$N, MATCH( MIN( IF( $M$7:$M$27 > $R7, $M$7:$M$27 ) ),$M:$M, 0 ) - 1 ) ) )
```

b.  Total as `TimeSerial`: Enter this `ArrayFormula` in `T7` then copy downwards *(cells number format is `[hh]:mm`)*

```
= IF( $Q7 > $R7, "!Err", 1/24 * SUM(
  INDEX($O:$O, MATCH( MIN( IF( $M$7:$M$27 >= $Q7, $M$7:$M$27 ) ),$M:$M, 0 ) ) :
  INDEX($O:$O, MATCH( MIN( IF( $M$7:$M$27 > $R7, $M$7:$M$27 ) ),$M:$M, 0 ) - 1 ),
- INDEX($N:$N, MATCH( MIN( IF( $M$7:$M$27 >= $Q7, $M$7:$M$27 ) ),$M:$M, 0 ) ) :
  INDEX($N:$N, MATCH( MIN( IF( $M$7:$M$27 > $R7, $M$7:$M$27 ) ),$M:$M, 0 ) - 1 ) ) )
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one. Good to know, that you can build a celladress with `INDEX`.

Comment: I just finished to try out your answer and it works very nicely! I have had some hard time with Excel 2011 because after the set with `INDIRECT` it keeps on crashing after modifying functions, don't know why. I didn't know you can build celladdress with `INDEX` (I was sure that I tried it, but with unsuccess ... maybe I was doing something wrong). Thanks also for your support in date data type, but it was unnecessary, thank you anyway. I prefer your answer for exposition clarity and examples support (I want to precise that also OverflowStacker answer did solve my problem!) Thanks to both!

Comment: @pippo `INDIRECT` is a so called volatile function. It always gets calculated whenever u do something in a workbook, for example modifying or deleting a cell. It shouldn't cause crashes though. :D

Comment: I don't know why but after using that formula Excel keeps on crashing ... before yesterday, I never had such a problem. I noticed a much slower time of response whenever I insert a data into my worksheet, and if I do: insert an array formula, press meta+enter and return to point to that cell for modify my formula, Excel crashes! I thought of `INDIRECT` is time consuming as you said to me in your answer ... if I wait a bit after I write a formula and pressed enter, it will not crash ... trying to find out why

Comment: `INDIRECT` could be *"indirectly"* responsible for the crashes, bear in mind volatility in a `FormulaArray` and probably a workbook that has a good volume of calculations.

Comment: Regarding the data type, just remember that stackoverflow is expected to be a repository of knowledge, therefore questions and answers serve a much larger audience than the asker.

Comment: You are right about data type question. I never know if writing here for more stuff than needed could be a good solution in regard of the huge amount of questions asked daily about the same argument, so ... I'm good with "repetita iuvant" ;)

Comment: about `INDIRECT`, I continue experimenting on formulae but without luck. In certain situations, it seems that also workbooks without `INDIRECT` crashes, don't know why yet. Keeping empty preferences folders and co.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a bit of a solution would be **ARRAY FORMULA CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**

```
    =SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("C"&MATCH(MIN(IF($A$1:$A$12>E4,$A$1:$A$12)),A:A,0)-1&":C"&MATCH(MIN(IF($A$1:$A$12>=D4,$A$1:$A$12)),A:A,0))-INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(MIN(IF($A$1:$A$12>E4,$A$1:$A$12)),A:A,0)-1&":B"&MATCH(MIN(IF($A$1:$A$12>=D4,$A$1:$A$12)),A:A,0)))
```

but it uses `INDIRECT` which can be pretty slow on big databases. The green cell contains the formula.

[image]

I have added a date before. You can input also dates which are not occuring in the table.

I skipped the `am` and `pm`, but if the cells are properly formatted as dates there should be no problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tested it and it works very nicely, I didn't know about `INDIRECT` function, many thanks! I adjust your formula to my needs in order to stop if it reaches blank values also in column B (because at certain point my data set stops without any other date next to the last one), introducing this formula: `IF.ERROR(MATCH(MIN(IF($A:$A>E4;$A:$A));$A:$A);MATCH(TRUE;LEN(B:B)=0;))` (no problem with big databases, I'm lucky that is a small one!). Thanks!

Comment: Ah, and I change the `SUMPRODUCT` function in only `SUM`. Is there a particular reason why I need to take `SUMPRODUCT` here?

Comment: I started with another approach and then left it in there. I figured later, that a `SUM` would be sufficient, but didn't think it was necessary to change. Maybe this just shows how much i like the `SUMPRODUCT` over anything else. :D

Comment: A smart approach to identify the `target` range, I'm using it to propose a non-volatile formula using `INDEX` instead of INDIRECT`

Comment: @EEM Well, I'm not the smart one. :) I just took it from [here](http://www.excelformeln.de/formeln.html?welcher=204). It's german though.

Comment: It seems like a good page *(I bookmarked)*, thanks for the tip… (I don't speak German, but got a *"translator"*…